# WooCommerce order variation products by price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom shop page with a custom loop, and I am trying to sort by highest and lowest prices. All products are variable products, but each variation has the same price. The code for my query is a bit complex, with conditionals, so I'll just show the var_dump of my query args here

```html
array(6) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "product" ["paged"]=> int(1) ["order"]=> string(4) "desc" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_price" ["orderby"]=> string(14) "meta_value_num" ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" ["field"]=> string(7) "term_id" ["terms"]=> int(35) } } }
```

You can see I set the meta_key to _price, order to a url parameter (either "asc" or "desc", and orderby to the meta_value_num. In this case, since order is "desc", it should show highest to lowest, but it's showing a product of price $1 near the top, and $70 near the bottom.

The actual order I'm getting back is $83, $1, $83 on sale for $75, and $70. As you ca see, the order is hap hazardous.

Comment: I have found the problem is with the post_types_order plugin. It seems to be overriding my custom query. I need to find out how to make this plugin compatible with my query.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! The problem was with the post types order plugin that I had installed. It was ordering my products for me automatically! I had to deselect a setting in the plugin settings for auto sorting, and now if I want to use that plugin's functionality on other queries, I need to include 'orderby' => 'menu_order' into query parameters.